# How to calculate ethash in python?

Tags: python, difficulty, ethash

I am trying to use `ethash(hash(blockHeader),nonce) < TARGET` to prove that the block was mined with at least a minimum difficulty.

**Is the formula above correct?**

When I try to use ehtereum.pow.ethash from pyethereum:

```
from ethereum.pow import ethash
difficulty = 3963642329
block_number = 4156209
nonce = int('0xf245822d3412da7f', 16)
block_hash = 0x47b8f62c1400dae65105d2f8e03824bfc58481c0b32f45788ad3378fbc05e9f6
cache = ethash.mkcache(block_number)
ethash = hashimoto_light(block_number, cache, block_hash, nonce)
print(ethash)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    cache = ethash.mkcache(block_number)
  File "(environment_path)/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethereum/pow/ethash.py", line 15, in mkcache
    while len(cache_seeds) <= block_number // EPOCH_LENGTH:
NameError: name 'EPOCH_LENGTH' is not defined
```

**Am I doing it wrong?** Or is there a bug in ethereum.pow.ethash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ethereum` module is not maintained. Check out `pyethash` for the same purpose.

You can import like:

```
from pyethash import (
    EPOCH_LENGTH,
    hashimoto_light,
    mkcache_bytes,
)
```

[`py-evm` uses it to check proof of work](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm/blob/e5cf81fe45a9a839a10bc7106cdfa76a0eb0f2fe/eth/consensus/pow.py#L53-L68) like so:

```
def check_pow(block_number: int,
              mining_hash: Hash32,
              mix_hash: Hash32,
              nonce: bytes,
              difficulty: int) -> None:
    validate_length(mix_hash, 32, title="Mix Hash")
    validate_length(mining_hash, 32, title="Mining Hash")
    validate_length(nonce, 8, title="POW Nonce")
    cache = get_cache(block_number)
    mining_output = hashimoto_light(
        block_number, cache, mining_hash, big_endian_to_int(nonce))
    if mining_output[b'mix digest'] != mix_hash:
        raise ValidationError("mix hash mismatch; {0} != {1}".format(
            encode_hex(mining_output[b'mix digest']), encode_hex(mix_hash)))
    result = big_endian_to_int(mining_output[b'result'])
    validate_lte(result, 2**256 // difficulty, title="POW Difficulty")
```

Where the [cache is generated and stored](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm/blob/e5cf81fe45a9a839a10bc7106cdfa76a0eb0f2fe/eth/consensus/pow.py#L32-L50) with:

```
# Type annotation here is to ensure we don't accidentally use strings instead of bytes.
cache_seeds = [b'\x00' * 32]  # type: List[bytes]
cache_by_seed = OrderedDict()  # type: OrderedDict[bytes, bytearray]
CACHE_MAX_ITEMS = 10


def get_cache(block_number: int) -> bytes:
    while len(cache_seeds) <= block_number // EPOCH_LENGTH:
        cache_seeds.append(keccak(cache_seeds[-1]))
    seed = cache_seeds[block_number // EPOCH_LENGTH]
    if seed in cache_by_seed:
        c = cache_by_seed.pop(seed)  # pop and append at end
        cache_by_seed[seed] = c
        return c
    c = mkcache_bytes(block_number)
    cache_by_seed[seed] = c
    if len(cache_by_seed) > CACHE_MAX_ITEMS:
        cache_by_seed.popitem(last=False)  # remove last recently accessed
    return c
```

Comment: Thank You.
I tried this, but it says that mix_hash != result. What am I doing wrong? 

block_number = 4156209
difficulty = 3963642329
nonce = unhexlify('0xf245822d3412da7f'[2:])
block_hash = unhexlify( '0x47b8f62c1400dae65105d2f8e03824bfc58481c0b32f45788ad3378fbc05e9f6'[2:])
mix_hash = unhexlify( '0x0c0026c706351083c0a913e084dee16ca133b813baa6a174e4fb179d9f2ecc52'[2:])

Comment: And it tells me that my difficulty somehow mismatches. Dose this have to do with the fact that I am using a block from ropsten?

Comment: Ropsten will work too. Trinity (built on py-evm) is validating pow using that code on Ropsten.