# Introductory sources to understand and implement Ethash mining?

Tags: mining, ethminer, ethash

I am looking for a straightforward source of article or scripts like the excellent blog post ["Bitcoin mining the hard way"](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoin-mining-hard-way-algorithms.html) to understand how Ethash proof-of-work works, how DAG generation works, and how the blocks are validated. Something that uses a high level language like Python to explain. I am an avid programmer in Python and knows C++ and knows what a hash function is.

I guess the first goal is to be able to go through the block hashing process with Python using a library like `pycryptodome` to produce a hash of an existing block, similar to what that block post for Bitcoin mining explained. Then I would like to connect to a Stratum pool in Python and try the mining process; of course, I am not trying to actually mine on CPU in Python and this is only for learning. My end goal is I would like to understand enough the code structure to be able to modify and contribute to [ethminer](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer).

I've looked at the official [ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/ethash) binding which is simply a binding of the underlying C++ code (so still hard to read to get the overview), is no longer maintained, and fails/very hard to compile on Windows.

According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60986/how-to-calculate-ethash-in-python) the `ethereum` module is no long maintained.

[This `eth-hash` Python library](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-hash) that implements `keccak256` seems very promising but I still don't know how to use it to hash information in a block, how it relates to DAG, etc.

[This script](https://github.com/lukovkin/ethash/blob/master/ethash.py) is probably the closest things I found but there is not much commentary to it.

I also know that [`Trinity`](https://trinity.ethereum.org/) exists, but is there a particular part of that that simply demonstrates how Ethashing and mining works?

Comment: Does this help at all? -> https://eth.wiki/en/concepts/ethash/ethash

Comment: Thanks this looks great actually! I will read through it